# Problem with Z-index of the controls in WIXUI(Problem of overlapping)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to design a dialog box for License aggrement and other dialog boxes.

Now if I set a image(.jpg/.bmp) in background of my dialog box then the checkbox will get disappear,and it is not visible until I hover the mouse over it. And the same problem appears with a pushbutton.

*) I first thought it could be because of the large size of the image but I also tried with smaller sized images and the problem existed with them too.

*) I also tried with changing the z-index of the controls but this still did not solve my problem.

Where is the problem?. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this beside implementing non native Windows Installer UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the dialogs included in the UI extension, you should be able to examine similar dialogs and work backwards to figure out what's going on. There's a background bitmap on the welcome dialog for example.

http://wix.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wix/wix/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/

**Edit:** In response to the comment about the Office 2007 installation experience, Office uses an external UI, not the built in stuff that Windows Installer provides. The setup is in WiX, but the UI isn't - there's more than 20 MSI files on the Office 2007 Ultimate disk, the external UI hides all of this from you to make it appear as a single installation package when in reality it's actually a whole lot more complicated.

**Edit 2:** See http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/07/23/442584.aspx for a good starting point on implementing non-native Windows Installer UI

Comment: Thanx sascha,
I had already tried with customizing the default themes like WIX_Mondo,WIX_Minimal etc.
I have checked the above link too..

but above link too not showing any overlapping of controls..
In my scenario i have to make a background theme for my dialog box which can be a bitmap or jpg.
As windows office setup is the standard example of installer made through wix..In there also it use the background theme..and use th epushbutton over the image..
check the install experience of microsoft office 2007

Comment: so it means we cud not implement any image on background of dialog box of msi's ...isn't there any alternative.which u can suggest me to do??..

Comment: As mentioned in my response, there is a background bitmap on the Welcome dialog. So it is possible - http://wix.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/wix/wix/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WelcomeDlg.wxs?revision=1.5

Comment: Dear sascha,..In that dialog box it have use the image in background but it don use pushbutton over it..i mean the image is not cover all the dialog box.It leave the surface below for pushbutton..so in that only it wud not implement the overlapping of controls..i already tried that file and also build the whole project of wix v3.5 in cvs with tortoise cvs..
I just want to put a pushbutton over a image like in the installer of MS-Office 2007..Is there any way you knw to do that???

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding TabSkip attribute and now the checkbox is above the bitmap.

```
<Control Id="Image" Type="Bitmap" TabSkip="no" X="0" Y="0" Width="374" Height="234" Text="BitmapFile" />
```